# Rewrite Enterprise Hierarchy Head

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, overrides

I'm attempting to rewrite the Hierarchy head in enterprise. Right now I just have it fire for an xdebug which I know works in other files. This is what I have that I think should be working:

***app/core/local/Abc/ThemeSwitch/Block/Hierarchy/Head.php***

```
class Abc_Themeswitch_Block_Hierarchy_Head extends Enterprise_Cms_Block_Hierarchy_Head
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $node = Mage::registry('current_cms_hierarchy_node');

        xdebug_var_dump($node);

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

***app/core/local/Abc/ThemeSwitch/etc/config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_ThemeSwitch>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Abc_ThemeSwitch>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <themeswitch>
                <class>Abc_Themeswitch_Block</class>
            </themeswitch>
            <enterprise_cms>
                <rewrite>
                    <hierarchy_head>Abc_Themeswitch_Block_Hierarchy_Head</hierarchy_head>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_cms>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

***app/etc/modules/Abc_ThemeSwitch.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_ThemeSwitch>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Enterprise_Cms />
            </depends>
        </Abc_ThemeSwitch>
    </modules>
</config>
```